# Count number of entries?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML doc:

[image]

I have the XML doc here:

```
   XElement entries =
                    doc.Element("response").Element("entries");
```

How can I get a count of the number of entry in entries?

This example would be 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
entries.Elements("entry").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Element()` use `Elements()`, which delivers an `IEnumerable<>`. You can then count the number of entries. Using the `Count()`-method of `IEnumerable<>`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) for reference on MSDN.